# How would I convert a var into a string?

Tags: c#

```cs
string decisionPath1;

var _Key = Console.ReadKey(true); 

decisionPath1 = (string)_Key.Key;

while (_Key.Key == ConsoleKey.R) 
 ... //Do something
```

This is for a *school project* and I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: It is not actually a "var". "var" is only a convenience to tell the compiler "whatever it actually is". Console.ReadKey returns [`ConsoleKeyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo?view=netframework-4.8). It has a `Key` property which has a `ToString()` Method, which is what you want. So instead of `(string)_Key.Key` try `_Key.Key.ToString()`

Comment: var is not a type. Please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var)

Answer (score 8):

`var` is just a way of implicitly declaring the type of the variable. `Console.ReadKey()` is declared to return `ConsoleKeyInfo`, so your declaration is *exactly* equivalent to:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo _Key = Console.ReadKey(true);
```

To find the string representation for `desionPath1`, you could use `_Key.KeyChar.ToString()` potentially. You should look at the documentation for [`ConsoleKeyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo?view=netframework-4.8) to see what's available.

Alternatively, if you're just wanting to read text from the console, you might want to use `Console.ReadLine()` or similar instead of `Console.ReadKey`.

Answer (score 0):

You need KeyChar property for this after that you can convert char to string. Key part is in code:

```
string desionPath1 = _Key.KeyChar.ToString();
```

You can look code in here

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         var _Key = Console.ReadKey(true); 

         string desionPath1 = _Key.KeyChar.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(desionPath1);
    }
}
```

Comment: _Fatal Error: Console.ReadKey() is not supported in .NET Fiddle._

Comment: Okey fiddle not support Console.ReadKey prop but it will run on local computer. I am editing right now